# binary operator '/' cannot be applied to two 'Double' operands

Tags: swift

While trying to execute this block of code in Swift 3, I encountered the error: binary operator '/' cannot be applied to two 'Double' operands

```
var array2 = [8, 7, 19, 20]

for (index, value) in array2.enumerated() {
    array2[index] = Double(value) / 2.0
}
```

Yet this works

```
var array2 = [Double]()
array2 = [8, 7, 19, 20]

for (index, value) in array2.enumerated() {
    array2[index] = value / 2.0
}
```

Why doesn't the first block of code work?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The error is a bit misleading.

In the first set of code, `array2` is implicitly declared as an array of `Int`. So any attempt to assign a value to an index of `array2` will require an `Int` value.

The problem is that `Double(value) / 2.0` results in a `Double` value, not an `Int`. So the compiler is looking for a version of `/` that returns an `Int`. And that version expects two `Int` parameters. Since you are supplying two `Double` parameters, you get the error mentioned in your question.

The solution is to either cast the result to an `Int` or use two `Int` parameters to `/`.

```
var array2 = [8, 7, 19, 20]

for (index, value) in array2.enumerated() {
    array2[index] = Int(Double(value) / 2.0) // cast to Int
}
```

or

```
var array2 = [8, 7, 19, 20]

for (index, value) in array2.enumerated() {
    array2[index] = value / 2 // Use two Int
}
```

The result will be the same in this case. `8` will be replaced with `4`. `7` will be replaced with `3`, etc.

The second set of code works as-is because you declare the array to be filled with `Double` so everything matches up with the correct type.

Comment: Note that `Int(...)` is *not* a cast – you cannot cast between different numeric types in Swift. It's a *conversion* through using `Int`'s initialiser.

Answer (score 2):

For the first one, your array is of type `Int` hence doing `array2.enumerated()` gives you `value` as an `Int`. When you do this to it, `Double(value) / 2.0`, the final result returned is of type `Double` which is incompatible with your array type.

For the second one though, you explicitly declared an array of `Double` hence `array2.enumerated()` returns `value` as a `Double` so performing the operation works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

rmaddy's answer is correct as to why you are seeing the issue, the implicit Int declaration.  For the sake of completeness. There are a couple ways to fix this, casting is one;  another not yet mentioned here is to extend Double to include this case, if you need to do this enough you can simply define your own version of Double / Int and control how Swift handles it within your own function.

```
extension Double {
    static func / (left: Double, right: Int) -> Double {
        return left / Double(right)
    }
}
```

You can always add another function handling the reverse case an Int / Double, etc...

Comment: Something new! How to use this?